# Using CXF with Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: servlets, spring-boot, cxf

I am working on a web service host application in which using cxf with spring boot. when I register cxf servlet with following code web service side works and I can see published wsdls.

However after setting cxf servlet Spring boot actuator and rest endpoints not working and returning 404. How can I solve this issue ?

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean cxfServlet() {
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/soap-api/*");
}
```

Comment: Do you still have `spring-webmvc` on the classpath? It's usually pulled in via a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-web`.

Comment: When It was not working I added spring-webmvc, but it didnt resolve error.

Answer (score 1):

Although I dont know the reason, when I set a name like below it starts working.

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean cxfServlet() {
    ServletRegistrationBean cxf = new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/soap-api/*");
    cxf.setName("cxfServlet");
    return cxf;
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you share a working example? Java has many alternatives for web services. I tried as much as Edison and still no solution. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple spring boot configuration I use.

```
@Configuration
@Import(value = { JaxRsConfig.class })
public class CxfRestConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/cxf/*");
    }

    @Component
    public class CustomSpringComponentScanServer
            extends AbstractSpringComponentScanServer {

        @Override
        protected String getAddress() {
            return "/api";
        }

        @Bean
        public Server jaxRsServer() {
            super.getFeatures().add(new LoggingFeature());
            return super.createJaxRsServer();
        }

    }

}
```

**Note:** With ComponentScanner you need to annotate your service class with Spring annotations along with @Path Annotation at class level.

If you do not want list of apis in http://localhost:8080/cxf you can directly remove the custom class I had written and you can import directly as shown below.

```
@Import(value = { JaxRsConfig.class, SpringComponentScanServer.class })
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same problem with Kotlin and this post indirectly helped me. My code was like this

```java
@Bean
fun dispatcherServlet(): ServletRegistrationBean<CXFServlet>? {
    return ServletRegistrationBean(CXFServlet(), "/*")
}
```

After changing the method name from `dispatcherServlet` to `cxfServlet` the actuator magically started to work.

```java
@Bean
fun cxfServlet(): ServletRegistrationBean<CXFServlet>? {
    return ServletRegistrationBean(CXFServlet(), "/*")
}
```

I guess it was conflicting with some Spring default servlet.

Comment: Applies to Java (of course) but that was the only change that made actuator work again for me.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like there is a clash between servlets.

You can check it in your logs. There should be:

```
2017-04-01 15:34:04,029 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.w.s.ServletRegistrationBean - Mapping servlet: 'CXFServlet' to [/soap-api/*]

2017-04-01 15:34:04,031 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.w.s.ServletRegistrationBean - Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
```

There should be exactly two servlets and the path should be different.

If there is one missing the enpoints won't work.

`dispatcherServlet` is spring default one to handle actuator metrics

Answer (score 0):

Its works for me

```
  @Bean
  @Primary
  public DispatcherServletPath dispatcherServletPath() {
    return () -> "";
  }
  
  @Bean
  public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServletActuator() {
    return new DispatcherServlet();
  }

  @Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean<CXFServlet> dispatcherServlet() {
    ServletRegistrationBean<CXFServlet> cxf = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new CXFServlet(), "/v1/*");
    cxf.setName("cxfServlet");
    return cxf;
    
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).